# "Orthogonal" Hadamard matrices with entries $\pm 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, contest-math

This question is related to problem A4 of Putnam 2005. The original statement of the problem is

> Let $H$ be a $n\times n$ matrix with entries $\pm 1,$ and are mutually orthogonal. Suppose $H$ has a $a\times b$ submatrix with all entries $1.$ Then $ab \leq n.$

My question here is: must we have $n=2^m$ for some $m?$ It is quite easy to see that $n$ must be divisible by $4$ if $n\geq 4.$

Apparently I can prove $n=2^m$ by induction, by finding a submatrix of $H$ with the same form. However, this is difficult, because it is hard to keep track of several vectors simultaneous. The cases gets increasingly complicated.

Comment: No. For example, we could have $ n = 12, 20$ (try finding them!). These are known as [Hadamard matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix). It is an open question if there's a Hadamard matrix of order $4k$ for every $k$.

Comment: It is [conjectured](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix) that such a matrix exists whenever $n$ is divisible by $4$, so no that is not necessarily the case. For example, some $12 \times 12$ Hadamard matrices are [given here](https://www.cs.miami.edu/home/burt/learning/Csc670.034/hadamard.html).

Comment: Note that it's not necessary to assume that $n$ is divisible by $4$ to make sense of this question. If there are no such matrices of size $n$, then it is "vacuously true" that every such matrix satisfies the condition that we're trying to prove.